# Rails 4 before_destroy does not prevent destruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's a simple Message model that i've set up.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :head, :text

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :receivers, class_name: MessageReceiver
  has_many :users, through: :receivers

  before_destroy :check_receivers

  private

  def check_receivers
    if self.receivers.empty?
      true
    else
      self.update(deleted: 1)
      false
    end
  end

end
```

The `:check_receivers` method works as expected when called directly (I remove it from the private section for that ofcource), but somehow it does not prevent a message from being destroyed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are they being *destroyed* or are they being *deleted*? `before_destroy` only fires on `destroy`. If `delete` is called, it will always proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
before_destroy :check_receivers
```

and try

```
has_many :receivers, class_name: MessageReceiver, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
```